# How to return the most match value via SequenceMatcher

Tags: django, matching, string-matching, textmatching, sequencematcher

I have to match a product's category name returned from API response and product's category name from data base.

For example:
api_category = "packing tape",

category names from DB = ["packing material", "packaging equipment"]

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

for e in Category.objects.all():
    matching_category = SequenceMatcher(None, api_category, e.name).quick_ratio()
```

```
0.36363636363636365
0.4090909090909091
```

I get floats, but I want to get the most matching element (e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem with using FuzzyWuzzy lib.

````
from fuzzywuzzy import process

def to_internal_value(self, data):
    internal_data = super().to_internal_value(data)
    api_category = process.extractOne(
            data.get("category"), Category.objects.values_list("name",flat=True))
    if api_category:
        category = Category.objects.filter(name__icontains=api_category[0]
                    ).first()
        if category:
                internal_data["category"] = category
    return internal_data```
````